# How to force index usage on DB2 while using a scalar value returned by a subquery?

Tags: performance, indexing, db2, database-performance, sql-tuning

The query runs on a huge table (1 billion records +)

> Select Col1 from TableA where identcol > (select bigint(identval) from
>   ParamTable)

(`identval` dataype is character and `identcol` is `BIGINT` )
This takes a long time and does a full table scan. When I replace the subquery and use a number value in the where clause for identcol, it starts to use the index on that column.

Is there a way to force DB2 to use this index, without specifying a literal value?  (DB2 9.7 luw on AIX )

edit: I found BETWEEN works with the subquery and an upper value, and also uses the index. Also if I remove the explicit cast to BIGINT it starts to use the index. But still would like to know the technical explanation /pointers. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour could be explained by insufficient information available to the query optimizer in the absence of a literal value.

When the literal value is supplied in the predicate, the optimizer can use the value distribution statistics for `tableA.identcol` to estimate how many rows might match the condition. Apparently, distribution is such that, given the literal value supplied, it considers index-based access better.

When instead you supply a subquery, the optimizer has no way of knowing what `identval` will be returned, so it makes a guess, which in your case turns out to be suboptimal.

To achive a more consistent optimization outcome you'll need to supply the optimizer with additional information. There are a few options you might try.

1. Create a statistical view, something like `create view sv1 as select Col1 from TableA,  ParamTable where TableA.identcol > ParamTable.identval` (and drop the `bigint()` from your query -- no need to confuse the optimizer even more). You will then need to enable statistical view optimization (`alter view sv1 enable query optimization`) and collect distribution statistics (`runstats on table sv1 with distribution`). However, seeing that `ParamTable` has only one row in it, one might assume that it changes quite frequently, so you'll need to make sure that statistics are updated each time `ParamTable.identval` changes.
2. Provide explicit selectivity estimate to the optimizer: `Select Col1 from TableA where identcol > (select bigint(identval) from ParamTable) selectivity 0.001`. Before you can do that, you will need to set the DB2 registry variable enabling this behaviour (`db2set DB2_SELECTIVITY=ALL`) and restart the instance. `0.001` indicates the proportion of the table, in this case 0.1%, that satisfies the condition. Replace `0.001` with the realistic estimate of the proportion of matching rows.
3. Create an index on `TableA (identcol, Col1)` if it does not already exist (and collect statistics for it) -- this might enable index-only access.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try the selectivity estimate and see if works. #3 is not possible in my specific case there are other considerations.

Comment: The explicit selectivity is not working with the subquery, it issues a SQL20046N needs a valid user-defined predicate.

Comment: Looks like you didn't execute `db2set DB2_SELECTIVITY=YES`, or didn't restart the instance after that, or both.

Comment: Try `db2set DB2_SELECTIVITY=ALL` instead.

Comment: ok thanks! I thought it was a syntax error from the message. Unfortunately I have no access for modifying the database parameters.